# Steam purchase issue

Tags: steam, realm-of-the-mad-god

When you attempt to purchase Realm of the Mad God's "Beginner's Package", it lists the purchase as buying "2600 Gold". The package contains more than just gold, so what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the transaction is the same for both the Beginner's Package and the 2600 Gold purchase.  Steam considers only the monetization of the package that contains 2600 gold.

The Beginner's Package still contains:

- 2 Character Slots
- 3 Vaults Chests
- 1 Karate Penguin Pet
- 2600 gold

If you do not receive the additional items, I suggest you do contact their support team.